# Elasticsearch SuggestResponse wrong on string with number

Tags: java, elasticsearch, autocomplete, fuzzy-search, search-suggestion

I've build an Auto-complete service with Elasticsearch 2.x.x. and one of my auto-completable values is "3M". I've configured the fuzziness to AUTO and my mapping is just default:

```
"mapping": {
    "type": "completion",
     "analyzer": "simple",
     "payloads": false,
     "preserve_separators": true,
     "preserve_position_increments": true,
     "max_input_length": 50
}
```

Based on [this documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html) the analyzers should be simple and Fuzziness AUTO means at **MAX** 2 spelling errors.

Here's the problem, whenever I type "1000000M" it still auto-completes "3M" although 1000000 and 3 are exceeding the limit of 2 spelling errors.

Does Elastic knows 1000000 and 3 are both numbers and I'm looking for {a number}M?

I would like the numbers to behave as actual String spelling errors because this is not the preferred behavior.

Even when I set Fuzziness to ZERO, it still corrects 1000000M to 3M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was fairly simple. All I to do was change my analyzer from [simple](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-simple-analyzer.html) to [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html). One thing to keep in mind though is that keyword doesn't use the lowercase analyzer which means your Auto-completions will be case sensitive unless .toLowercase() it all yourself